# Two web applications on one Web Role - config issue

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I am attempting to publish two web application onto one web role as just [this article](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/).

I have the following error:

> The role 'AzureWebTest2' exists in the configuration file without a definition in the service definition.

Here is my `ConfigDefinition.csdef`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AzureWebTestCloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <WebRole name="AzureWebTest" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="AzureWebTest.mydomain.com" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="Web2" physicalDirectory="..\..\AzureWebTest2">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="AzureWebTest2.mydomain.com"  />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

My Cloud Service project:

[image]

I assume that it is because there is no `<WebRole name="AzureWebTest2">` entry in `ConfigDefinition.csdef`.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you've got a second role included in your image of your CloudService deployment project. Remove that role. your project is included via the `physicalDirectory` property on the `<site>` tag.

Comment: You are correct. In ServiceDefinition.csdef file there is one web role with two sites, but in CloudService deployment there are two web roles defined.

Answer (score 1):

In ServiceDefinition.csdef file you have one web role with two sites, but in CloudService project you added two web roles. 
You need to delete second web role 'AzureWebTest2'. And I think everything should work now. If not please tell.

Maybe this links can help you:

http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/11/azure-running-multiple-web-sites-in-a-single-webrole/ 
http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/